# Is there any official terminology about something like double quotes "" grammar?

Tags: terminology, formal-grammars, parsers

In many programming language string is a token.

For example:

```
 token               ::= '"' string
                       | digit nat

 string              ::= char string
                       | '"'

 nat                 ::= digit nat
                       | ϵ
```

This is a LL(1) grammar for some programming language's toke grammar.

When parsing a `string`, there is no need to check follow set, because there is a `"` at the end of each `string`.

Comparing with `nat`, `string` is more easy to parse.

My question is

Is there any official terminology about this kind of grammar?

Thanks.

---

Editing:

There was some mistake in the original grammar, thanks @rici for pointing out my mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOLLOW sets are not used in the parsing of either `string` or `nat`. In both cases, the parser merely needs to determine if the input is in a set of valid symbols. In the case of `nat`, the valid symbols are digits; in the case of `string`, they are characters other than `"`. (In real languages, the parser would also be checking for `\`). But in both cases, a check is necessary, and there's no good criterion for saying one test is "simpler" than another. (In practice, both checks are likely to be a simple table lookup. So they're O(1).)

FOLLOW sets are only needed when the grammar contains ε productions. Even then, the parser's actions are not complicated. What is more complicated is building the parser, something which only happens once. It's not really that big of a deal, but it's sufficiently notable that "ε-free grammars" are a thing. I don't think there's any common vocabulary to describe the difference between explicitly and implicitly-terminated repetition, and any way the distinction will be very hard to define strictly. Your `string` would be parsed by a parser which used a different rule to collect the trailing `"`, and it's quite possible that the two parsers end up with the same implementation.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. But what I mean is when parsing a token, when the head char of the input is a `"`, we can enter into a STRING State, then we check any chars until meet another `"`, then we can leave the STRING State and go to a FINAL State.

Comment: Comparing with `nat`, this strategy is impossible, because nat has a ϵ production. We must check the follow-set of nat.

Comment: In other words, for string token, we have two ways to write the grammar. One is in the question, another way is 
`token  ::= '"' string '"' | nat `
`string ::= char string | ϵ`
`nat ::= digit nat | ϵ`
If you write grammar like this, then we need check string's follow set, because now `string` has a ϵ production. But for nat token, there is only one way to write, it always has a ϵ production..

Comment: @chansey: Writing `nat` with an ϵ  production is an error. A `nat` needs to have at least one digit. You're correct that the alternative grammar for string needs an ϵ production.

Comment: But the parser never consults the FOLLOW set. The FOLLOW set has already been taken into account when the parser's action table is constructed. The parser just looks up an action in its action table; whether that action was computed by reference to a FOLLOW set or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake! The grammar should be rewritten as `token ::= '"' string | digit nat`. Sorry, I have to edit the question.

Comment: @chansey: That's what happens when you using LL(1) parsers, I guess. I'd write that as `token ::= string | nat; string ::= '"' char-list '"'; char-list ::= ϵ | char-list char; nat ::= digit | nat digit`, which is LR(1) and (imho) clearer. In practice, scanners use regular expressions which are less powerful and frequently ambiguous (but the ambiguity doesn't matter), and can be compiled into DFAs.

Comment: Check out the syntax of JSON strings. That one is rather complicated. Well, the syntax for numbers is quite complex as well :-)

Comment: @gnasher729: `["]([^"\\]|\\(["/\\bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}))*["]`. The one that is complicated is JavaScript (or Python) because they allow embedded expressions in strings.

Comment: It’s even more complicated because of restrictions not in the grammar. The 4 byte unicode sequences must be valid UTF-16 values, and control characters are not allowed).

Comment: @gnasher729: "**Any  code  point** may  be  represented  as  a  hexadecimal  escape  sequence." Recall that non-characters are still code points. The only invalid Unicode would be a lone surrogate, although I think there is a reading of ECMA-404 which allows surrogates to be passed through even if unpaired, leaving them to be rejected by some other mechanism. The control character restriction (for literal characters only prohibits `[\0-\037]`, which I should have added to my character class.

Comment: `["]([^"\0-\037\\]|\\(["/\\bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}))*["]`